# Nightly Builds Test against real database

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Is it a good practice to hit actual database for Integrations test(Not prod but pre prod DB) in Jenkins Night builds? The reason I am asking this is because our DAO uses procedures to perform simple CRUD operations so it is almost impossible to test operation like INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETE even against in memory H2 database.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal practice. DB is not `CRUD` only. There is can be whole packages, which you'd like to use in the integration test. I'd like to advise you to read about `testcontainers`. On one of my projects, we used step such as "prepare DB" and runned a lot of DDL operations script before the integration test. On another project, we used `testcontainers`

Comment: so you mean i can run integration test against  a PRE PROD database right?